# Mongoose Calling function for default value

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I have a Mongoose Schema where I am assigning a default value to a field by calling a function.

My schema

```
function fun(){
    let curr_time = moment().format();
    return curr_time;
};

let flagged_trans_schema = new Schema({
    time: {type: Date, default: fun},
});
```

I am facing a problem here, when I am writing `default: fun()` then the time field is not getting updated time, but when I am writing `default: fun` then time field value is updating every time.

Can anyone please tell me why it is happening?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using `default: fun()` sets the default to the result of calling the `fun` function at the time the schema is declared. Just once, and the default will be that value for all newly created model instances (or, possibly, documents from the database that didn't have the `time` field set).

Using `default: fun` sets the default to reference the `fun` function, and Mongoose is smart enough to know that this means that it should call that function each time a new model instance is created.

Comment: But the thing is my IDE which is webstorm is blacking out `default` line, don't know why it is doing?

Comment: I have no idea either, I don't use WebStorm myself. Try quoting `default`: `"default" : fun`